# jquery validate confirm password

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ to validate a form which will allow a user to change their existing settings.  The form has a field for a password as well as a field to confirm the password.  To leave the password unchanged, I instruct the user to leave it blank (maybe some more intuitive way to do this?), and the confirm password field is only shown if the user changes his/her password.

It works pretty well, but has two problems.  First, if you enter something in the password field and press tab, you don't go to the confirm password field, but the next field after that.  Second, if you enter something in the password field and press enter, the form is submitted before the confirm password is checked.  For some reason, this second deficiency doesn't manifest using the jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/4htKu/2/, but it does on the second identical demo http://tapmeister.com/test/validatePassword.html.  The code below is identical to the previous two mentioned demos.  I believe the problems relates to the confirm_password password being hidden, but am not certain.  What do I need to do to fix these two problems? Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <title>jQuery validation plug-in - main demo</title>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                $("#confirm_password").parent().hide();
                $("#password").val('').
                blur(function() {
                    $t=$(this);
                    if($.trim($t.val())!="" && !$t.hasClass('error')) {$("#confirm_password").parent().show();}
                    else if($.trim($t.val())=="") {$("#confirm_password").val('').parent().hide();}
                });

                // validate signup form on keyup and submit
                $("#signupForm").validate({
                    rules: {
                        firstname: {required: true,minlength: 2},
                        lastname: {required: true,minlength: 2},
                        username: {required: true,minlength: 2},
                        password: {required: true,minlength: 2},
                        confirm_password: {required: true,minlength: 2, equalTo: "#password"}
                    },
                    messages: {},
                    submitHandler: function(form) {alert("submitted");}
                });

            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <form class="cmxform" id="signupForm" method="get" action="">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Validating a complete form</legend>
                <p>
                    <label for="firstname">Firstname*</label>
                    <input id="firstname" name="firstname" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="lastname">Lastname*</label>
                    <input id="lastname" name="lastname" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="username">Username*</label>
                    <input id="username" name="username" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password">Password (Leave blank to remain unchanged)</label>
                    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="confirm_password">Confirm password</label>
                    <input id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" type="password" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="other">Other Non-required</label>
                    <input id="other" name="other" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp for controlling what element is hit on tab

Comment: From a usability perspective I would recommend changing the view of the confirm from onBlur to onKeypress. After each keypress in pass field check to see if something exists, and if so display confirm, else hide confirm.

Comment: @Syon.  Looks like you and Kevin agree.  I will test and post findings.  Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Liam,  I know (or maybe once knew:) about tabindex, but haven't used it for a while.  Something I definitely need to investigate, but think it might have to deal with the input not being visible at the time up tab is pressed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `.blur`, use `.keydown` and a `settimeout` to detect if the value is blank. If it isn't blank, show it, else, hide it.

```
$("#password").keydown(function() {
    var self = this, $self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ( $.trim(self.value) != "" && !$self.is(".error") ) {
            $("#confirm_password").parent().show();
            return;
        }
        $("#confirm_password").val('').parent().hide();
    },0);
});
```

As far as pressing enter, isn't that what it's supposed to do? submit the form?

The reason using `.blur` doesn't work is you are tabbing to the next field before the hidden field is shown. This code fixes that problem.

Comment: Thanks Kevin,  I will try .keydown.  As for pressing enter, it submits the form before the user has the opportunity to enter the confirm_password.  I think (hope) your solution might also fix it since it makes the confirm_password input visible thus will be validated.

Comment: @Kevin one question why you use the immediate timeout, I've not  seen that technique before.  Also user1032531 should probably remove the required rule for password, otherwise the logic of leaving it blank to not change the password doesn't make work. http://jsfiddle.net/4htKu/3/

Comment: @politus.  Agree about the required rule for password. Didn't mean to include it.

Comment: @Kevin.  I also don't see the need for the intermediate timeout, and it works find without it.  Seems like also keydown and keypress and keyup also works.  Thanks

Comment: Without the timeout, you are checking the value BEFORE it changes. For example, the input should not appear until after you type two characters if you don't use the timeout.

Comment: Here's an example without the setTimeout http://jsfiddle.net/4htKu/4/. Notice how it doesn't show the hidden field until after you type two characters, and if you type one character and then backspace it, the field shows up when it should be hidden. It's always 1 keydown behind if you don't use the setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Why not ask the user if they want to change their password with a checkbox? If its checked display the password fields, if not allow the form to be submitted.

Additional HTML:

```
<p>
    <label for="passwordChangeYes">Check if you want to change your password</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="passwordChangeYes" id="passwordChangeYes" value="Yes" />
</p>
```

Additional JS:

```
$("#password").hide();
$('#passwordChangeYes').one("click", function () {
    if ($('#passwordChangeYes').is(':checked')) {
            $("#password").fadeIn(400);
        }
    });
```

I'm not sure how to remove or add the required part from the validation portion on the checkbox click. But maybe this is a starting point?